# Search JPA complex object for nested object based on its value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, graph

Lets assume we have a complex JPA relation, a fraction of which looks like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class DiffEntity {

  private String diffId;

  public DiffEntity() {
    this.diffId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  }
  //...
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class ParentEntity extends DiffEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @Column
  private String name;

 //...
}

@Entity
public class Construct extends ParentEntity {

  @Column
  private String variable;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "construct", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Partconstruct> partconstructs;

 //...

 }

@Entity
public class Partconstruct extends ParentEntity {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "partconstruct", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Field> fields;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "partconstruct", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Hardparameter> hardparameters;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "construct_id")
  private Construct construct;

  //...
}

@Entity
public class Field extends ParentEntity {

  @Column
  private int fieldSize;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "partconstruct_id")
  private Partconstruct partconstruct;

  //...
}

@Entity
public class Hardparameter extends ParentEntity {

  @Column
  private String value;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "partConstruct_Id")
  private Partconstruct partConstruct;

  //...
}
```

We are concerned with `Construct` type objects. `Construct` is deeply cloned and persisted, having all its nested objects on the object graph being cloned too and getting a new `Id` (primary key). On every clone the `diffId` (from `DiffEntity` entity) stays the same (it serves the purpose of correlating objects for a diffing feature).

How would it be possible to search and get a reference for a specific `DiffEntity` given we have the below:

- a reference to the `Construnct` instance
- type of the nested object
- `diffId` we are after.

I have tried different versions of object graph traversers with reflection, which will work for a small in size `Construct` object, but once it becomes too big performance is very slow.

Is there any magic on the entity manager itself to achieve that ?